# How do I scroll the following code into a div view?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollview

I have a link that already has an onclick function that selects an item.

```
 {return "<a class='link' onClick='addtoSelectedList(this)'>Select</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

I want to scroll as soon as I click to a div id="abc". How do I apply to the code above?

Comment: post that as an answer @nnnnnn Its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding href="#abc" will work in you case :

```
return "<a class='link' href='#abc' onClick='addtoSelectedList(this)'>
     Select</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
```